# Mapping cones of multiples of the Hopf map $\eta$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\eta\colon S^3\to S^2$ be the Hopf map. Recall that the complex projective plane $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is the mapping space $C(\eta)$; $\pi_3(S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $\eta$. My question is: What is the homotopy types of the mapping space $C(2\eta)$, or generally, the homotopy type of the mapping space $C(k\eta)$?

[image]

Comment: One thing to note is that $\Sigma C(2\eta)\simeq S^5 \vee S^3$ because the suspension of $2\eta$ is null homotopic. More generally, $\Sigma C(2k\eta)\simeq S^5 \vee S^3$ and $\Sigma C((2k+1)\eta)\simeq \Sigma \mathbb{C}P^2$. $C(n\eta)$ also has a nontrivial cup product $x^2=ny$ where $x,y$ are the additive generators.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thank you very much. In general, is $C(n\eta)$ a manifold for $n\geq 2$? It seems that $C(n\eta)$ doesn't appear in the classification of simply-connected manifolds.

Comment: No: Poincare Duality!

Comment: @ConnorMalin I added a proof that shows the cup product formula $x^2=n^2y$ in $H^\ast(C(n\eta))$.  How did you get the formula $x^2=ny$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $x^2=ay$, then $a$ is called the Hopf invariant of $n\eta$. It is well known that the Hopf invariant is a homomorphism, so because the Hopf invariant of $\eta$ is $1$, the Hopf invariant of $n\eta$ is $n$.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say the error is $t\eta=\eta t$. Multiplication by an integer does not always commute in homotopy groups of spheres.

Comment: Thanks! I need to review some homotopy theory.